# installation of package ‘RcppCCTZ’ had non-zero exit status when install data table package

Tags: r, datatable, installation

i am trying to install the data table in my R.

```
1: In install.packages("data.table", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘RcppCCTZ’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("data.table", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("data.table", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘nanotime’ had non-zero exit status
```

I tried to install the RcppCCTZ 
install.packages("RcppCCTZ")

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppCCTZ’

Warning message:
In install.packages("RcppCCTZ") :
  installation of package ‘RcppCCTZ’ had non-zero exit status
```

it gives me the following error.

how can i fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Try them one by one and pay attention to the individual error messages.

Comment: Also: what OS and what version do you use? Maybe your compiler is too old? 
RcppCCTZ requires a new-ish compiler for the CCTZ library.  Lastly, theses are _suggested_ packages for `data.table` so you can still use it whil we work out what happens on your box.